# Add Padding-Right in .NET MVC Razor Pages

Tags: c#, css, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

After doing some Google searches and reading some StackOverflow answers, I tried adding this code (between the two **s, I intended to make that bold):

```
<div class="col-md-2 p-0">
                                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="GasForcedAir" name="GasForcedAir" id="gasForcedAir" class="form-check-input" onclick="heatSourceSelectOne(this.id)" **style="padding-right:200px !important;"**/><label>Gas Forced Air</label>
                            </div>
```

But there's still no space between the checkbox and it's label.  Would do you suggest I try instead?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with `razor pages`. Pay attention to this point when asking your question. Your question is related to `css`.  And to solve the problem Use `margin` instead of `padding`

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo to make checkbox and lable in the same line,and add space between them:

```
<div class="col-md-2 p-0 white-space:nowrap">
    <input type="checkbox" name="GasForcedAir" id="gasForcedAir" class="form-check-input" onclick="heatSourceSelectOne(this.id)" style="margin-right:20px"   /><label>Gas Forced Air</label>
</div>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Yiyi You, I used the 20 px and rebuilt (I used to just refresh the page in JavaScript) and it worked.